# How can I customize all my added menus which I added with navigationmenu.add()?

Tags: java, android

I want to change every layout of each added Menu. Here is the code:

```
private void addPlacesToMenu() {
    int index = 0;
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    NavigationMenu menu = (NavigationMenu)navigationView.getMenu();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    final ArrayList<String> allPlaces = placesDAO.allPlacesByName();
    for (String p : allPlaces) {
        menu.add(allPlaces.get(index));
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: I want to add an icon

Comment: Adding the icon programmatically might be a bit of trouble, wouldnt it be possible to add an icon in your layout-file(s)?